# How to make Sound Blaster X-Fi Xtreme Audio Notebook output to internal speakers with latest drivers?

Tags: laptop, drivers, speakers, creative

Just what the title said.

There was a utility on the driver CD which had a setting to redirect output to internal speakers, but it's quite old and is installed as a part of old drivers, so I'd like to avoid using it (or at least the outdated version) and there seems to be no new version available.

I'm using windows 7 64bit and drivers which came from windows update. They came with few utilities, but not the one I was looking for.

Comment: Does http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm help ?

Comment: @Sathya If I'm reading the site correctly, it's not what I need. I don't have an output which directly controls only internal speakers.